# Elasticsearch aggs curl request truncating results

Tags: curl, elasticsearch

I'm trying to get aggs from ES using the following command:

```
curl --user username:pwd -XGET 'localhost:9200/my_index-2016-06-14/_search?pretty' -d '
{
  "size": 0, 
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  },
  "aggs": {
    "my_stores": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "store",
        "size": 5000
      }
    }
  }
}
```

In my ES index, the "store" field contains one of several different store codes in the form "ABC-123CD". When I receive my results I'm getting something similar to the following for each value:

```
{
  "key" : "123cd",
  "doc_count" : 152
}
```

In other words, the results are being truncated, and I assume it's due to the hyphen in some way. How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem myself, and it was actually quite simple by just adding '.raw' to the field value as follows:

```
curl --user username:pwd -XGET 'localhost:9200/my_index-2016-06-14/_search?pretty' -d '
{
  "size": 0, 
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  },
  "aggs": {
    "my_stores": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "store.raw",
        "size": 5000
      }
    }
  }
}
```